# Problemas al cerrar un Toplevel orientado a objeto tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

aprovechando tiempo libre por la pandemia, estoy intentando aprender a programas con videos online, buscando por internet me encontre un codigo para levantar una ventana en tkinter orientada a objeto el codigo es el siguiente:

`

```
import tkinter as tk

class nombreclase(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
    self.parent = parent
 
  #aqui va el resto de codigo para tu ventana

if __name__=="__main__":
    raiz=tk.Tk()
    nombreclase(raiz).pack
    raiz.mainloop()
```

`
el problema se da cuando intento cerrar un modulo difenrente con esta misma estructura pero como un top level.

mi pantalla principal tiene este codigo

`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

class principal(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
       tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
       self.parent = parent

       self.fondo=tk.Frame(parent)
       self.fondo.pack()

       barraMenu=tk.Menu(raiz)
       raiz.config(menu=barraMenu)
       
       archivoMenu=tk.Menu(barraMenu, tearoff=0)
       archivoMenu.add_command(label="Unir a BBDD", command=self.avisoUnirBBDD)

       barraMenu.add_cascade(label="Archivo", menu=archivoMenu)

    def avisoUnirBBDD(self):
        valor=messagebox.askquestion("Unir a la Base de Datos","¿Estas Seguro que deseas Continuar?")
        if valor=="yes":
            from unirBBDD import unirBBDD
            unirBBDD(self.parent).lower()


if __name__ == "__main__":
   raiz= tk.Tk()
   principal(raiz).pack
   raiz.mainloop()
```

`
y el otro mudulo que deseo sea un Toplevel tiene el siguiente codigo:

`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox, filedialog

class unirBBDD(tk.Toplevel):

def __init__(self, ventana1, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, ventana1, *args, **kwargs)
    self.ventana1= ventana1

    self.fondo=tk.Frame(ventana1)
    self.fondo.pack()

    self.fondo2=tk.Frame(ventana1)
    self.fondo2.pack()

    abrirBBDD=tk.Label(self.fondo, text="BBDD a la que se desea unir:")
    abrirBBDD.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
    botonBBDD=tk.Button(self.fondo, text="Abrir Base de Datos", command=self.abrirBBDD)
    botonBBDD.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

    abrirCsv=tk.Label(self.fondo, text="Archivo 'CSV' del que se desea Unir")
    abrirCsv.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
    botonCsv=tk.Button(self.fondo, text="Abrir Archivo 'CSV'", command=self.abrirCSV)
    botonCsv.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

    aceptar=tk.Button(self.fondo2, text="Aceptar", command=self.unir)
    aceptar.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=30, pady=10)

    cancelar=tk.Button(self.fondo2, text="Cancelar", command=self.salir)
    cancelar.grid(row=4, column=1,padx=30, pady=10)

def salir(self):
    raiz.destroy()#aqui esta el problema

def abrirBBDD(self):
    archivoBBDD=filedialog.askopenfilename(title="abir")#, filetypes=(("Archivos SQLite","*.sl3"),("archivos de textos","*.txt"),("Todos los Archivos","*.*")))
    global nombreBBDD
    nombreBBDD=archivoBBDD.split("/").pop()
    if archivoBBDD!="":
        rutaBBDD=tk.Label(self.fondo, text=(archivoBBDD))
        rutaBBDD.config(fg="green")
        rutaBBDD.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10)

def abrirCSV(self):
    archivoCSV=filedialog.askopenfilename(title="abir", filetypes=(("Archivos CSV","*.csv"),("archivos de textos","*.txt"),("Todos los Archivos","*.*")))
    global nombreCSV
    nombreCSV=archivoCSV.split("/").pop()
    if archivoCSV!="":
        rutaBBDD=tk.Label(self.fondo, text=(archivoCSV))
        rutaBBDD.config(fg="green")
        rutaBBDD.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10)

def unir(self):
    import csv, sqlite3
    conexion=sqlite3.connect(nombreBBDD)
    cursor=conexion.cursor()

    reader=csv.reader(open(nombreCSV,'r'),delimiter=';')

    for row in reader:
        
        to_db=[str(row[0]),
               str(row[1]),
               str(row[2])]

        cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO denunciaObligatoria
                        VALUES(?,?,?)''', to_db)
    conexion.commit()
    conexion.close()
```

`
el error que genera es:

```
NameError: name 'raiz' is not defined
```

imagino que el preblema esta en la funcion "salir".

es mucho codigo y tal vez algo incoherente me disculpo pero intento dar a entender lo que intento, recuerden soy muy nuevo en este mundo apenas 1 mes, y deben explicarme lo mas simplemente posible, gracias...

Comment: Yuvone pero RAIZ no está definida en esa parte de tu código.. Solamente es llamado en esa función de Salir.. Que observando también, esa función no es llamada en ninguna parte del codigo

Comment: si es llamada en el boton cancelar 


    `cancelar=tk.Button(self.fondo2, text="Cancelar", command=self.salir)`


lo he cambiado a ventana1.destroy() pero nada lo que deseo es que cierre el Toplevel sin cerrar la principal, gracias..

Answer (score 0):

Tocando un poco encontre la solucion. el problema es que estaba definiendo mal al Toplevel, se debe definir de esta forma

```
class unirBBDD(tk.Toplevel):

def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
    self.ventana1=k.Toplevel(parent)
```

y para la funcion o metodo se tiene que indicar de esta forma:

```
def salir(self):
    self.ventana1.destroy()
```